# low oil pressure alert and engine flush

Tags: engine, oil-filter

[image]I have 140.000 kms diesel engine second hand.
the low oil alert fired 2 times when driving on high revs for a while.
at low it does not fire.
got the car in the garage and they propose a clean of the oil intake filter and injectors. 1800euros
I was wondering if a engine flush would be a simpler way. using some engine cleaning products.
any experience with these?

Comment: 140k kms/89.4k miles is not a lot of mileage, Oil/filter changed regularly? What does draiined oil feel like? Gritty, metal deposits or clean and free of particles? Previous owner may not have changed oil on a regular basis. If possible, draining oil and removing the oil pan to see inside for sludge, oil screen blockage, may help determine if  damage occurred. The oil screen blocks large particles unless sludge buildup blocks the oil pickup tube. Reassembling and filling with good diesel motor oil and filter, run several hundred kms, draining to examine oil may help flush remaing sludge,

Comment: I added a photo of the oil. it is black after a oil change, maybe 300kms only and it is totally black. don't notice particles.

Comment: the garage was going to do what you suggest. open and change the oil screener. but they charge 1800eur, the car cost me 9000...

Comment: wouldn't the engine cleaner do something similar?

Comment: 300kms on fresh oil turning black is fine as long as it doesn't feel gritty. Diesel engines tend to create more blowby gases from normal high compression so oil turns dark quickly and not an indication of anything wrong. What no one mentioned is removing the oil pressure sending unit and temporarily installing an oil pressure gauge to monitor actual pressures. Much easier to see actual pressures to determine whether or not the oil pressure sending unit is faulty. You'll have to know expected pressures.